# How can I make my dropdown work with display: none and display: block?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<li class="profile-dropdown">
  <a href="/profile" class="login-btn">Profil</a>                               
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Test1</li>
    <li><a href="/">Test2</li>
    <li><a href="/">Test3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/profile/logout" class="login-btn">Logout</a></li>
```

With the following css rules

```
.profile-dropdown ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: all 0s ease 1s; /*delay 1s*/
} 
.profile-dropdown:hover ul { 
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;

  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  left: -15px;

  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

It would a part of my webpage's navbar. I'd like to make a dropdown which would only appear when a user hovers over it's parent li element. With the visibility rule it works fine, the delay is applied to the hover animation so I can hover over the hidden li elements within the ul and it still remain visible.

However it only looks okay when I'm hovering. It looks horrible without hovering because my container is slightly larger when I'm using visibility.

When I'm using *display: none* instead of *visibility: hidden* and *display: block* instead of *visibility: visible* than it looks okay but the delay is not applied so I can't hover the li elements within the hidden ul.

**Is there a way to make visibility not affect the size of my elements or to make the delay work with the display rule?**

Edit: [Without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV1ca.png) [With hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUxP5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.profile-dropdown ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
} 
.profile-dropdown:hover ul { 
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: initial;
}
```

```html
<li class="profile-dropdown">
  <a href="/profile" class="login-btn">Profil</a>                               
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Test1</li>
    <li><a href="/">Test2</li>
    <li><a href="/">Test3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/profile/logout" class="login-btn">Logout</a></li>
```

I have added position absolute so when you use visibility as hidden the extra space is removed and added position back to initial to show when you hover your mouse on a list to show sub menu on the right space.

```
.profile-dropdown ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  position: absolute;
} 
.profile-dropdown:hover ul { 
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  position: initial;
}
```

I have used the same HTML as yours

```
<li class="profile-dropdown">
  <a href="/profile" class="login-btn">Profil</a>                               
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Test1</li>
    <li><a href="/">Test2</li>
    <li><a href="/">Test3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/profile/logout" class="login-btn">Logout</a></li>
```

Check my codepen

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shads06/pen/KKpVKxM)

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you :)

So basically without hover it was on the same dimension than it's parent and this is why it took more space, right?

Comment: The difference between display: none; and visibility: hidden; is when you use visibility: hidden; that the content of the element is invisible but the element stays in its original position and size but when we use display: none; the element is removed completely.

Comment: To remove the size of the element after visibilitty: hidden; I used position: absolute; and this makes the element positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element and when user hover mouse elements position is again set back to initial to its actual position

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet, I hope this is what you are looking into

```css
 ul{
     list-style:none;
     padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
    }
    .profile-dropdown{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid;
    position:relative;
    }
    .profile-dropdown ul {
    display:none;
    
      transition: all 0s ease 1s; /*delay 1s*/
    } 
    .profile-dropdown:hover ul { 
     display:block;
      opacity: 1;

      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      left: 10px;

      transition-delay: 0s;
    }
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li class="profile-dropdown">
      <a href="/profile" class="login-btn">Profile</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Test1</li>
        <li><a href="/">Test2</li>
        <li><a href="/">Test3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="profile-dropdown"><a href="/profile/logout" class="login-btn">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Not really. With display: none and display: block I can't make the hover animation last longer so the hidden element is instantly disappears after I hover out of the profile-dropdown element.

Comment: I added 2 pictures to illustrate the problem.